# ember handlebars: find where component/helper/variable is defined

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Given some handlebars code like this:

```
{{ui.select param1="foo" param2="bar"}}
```

How could I find out where `ui.select` is defined?

(I happen to be on Ember 2.13)

Comment: I don't know the best way to find these definitions but I've always reverted to searching code. If that really is the best way to find these things I'd love a handful commonly used of regex's to find handlebars definitions

Comment: for helpers: search `.js` files for: `export default Ember.Helper` (older syntax) and `export default helper(` (newer syntax).  for components, search `.hbs` files by name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because this contains a `.` this comes from a contextual component.

so first find out where `ui` comes from. Probably you have something like this:

```
{{#my-component as |ui|}}
  {{ui.select ...}}
{{/my-component}}
```

Then you have to check the `my-component` and find out what `ui` is assigned to in the `{{yield}}`.

Comment: This was the trick! Thanks Lux. (EDIT: moving to new question, will link in a sec) I added a second part to the question regarding finding addon-defined helpers, I can move that to a new question if you want but figured it'd be better to keep things a little more centralized. @ctcpip

Comment: Here's the second question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49459538/ember-handlebars-find-which-addon-is-defining-a-helper-not-present-in-app-help