# ember handlebars: find which addon is defining a helper (Not present in app/helpers)

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

Having a hard time finding out where a helper not in `app/helpers` is defined. The helper was very generically named, I searched my package.json for the helper name but there was nothing. I was stuck hunting around with google to try and figure out what addon defined it.

Given some helper (`{{totally-generic-name param1="foo"}}`) how would one go about finding where it's defined?

(I happen to be on Ember 2.13)

(Note: the helper was `contains` defined in `ember-composable-helpers`, so it would have been a LITTLE helpful to search package.json for "helper" but that is a pretty tedious in-direct way of searching, which have may not even yielded the answer)

Comment: I'm guessing you COULD just search node_modules and bower_components for for .js files containing `export default Ember.Helper` (older syntax) and `export default helper` (newer syntax). And then for finding addon-defined components, search .hbs files by name – (Credit @ctcpip: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49390867/ember-handlebars-find-where-component-helper-variable-is-defined/49452304#comment85784766_49390867)

Comment: Would it be possible to define an editor/ide plugin that takes care of finding all handlebars component/helper/etc definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the easiest way is to run a development build of your application (`ember serve`), open development tools of your browser and open a file called `<your-app-name>/helpers/<helper-name>.js`. In the first line of the file, you see from where it is imported.

Let's assume your application name is *foo* and you have installed `ember-array-helper`. Run your application via `ember serve` and open it in Chrome. Go to development tools *Source* section. Search for `helpers/array.js` in subsection *Network*. You could search for a file per name via <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>. If the helper is provided by an addon this file is autogenerated. It looks like the following:

```
define('foo/helpers/array', ['exports', 'ember-array-helper/helpers/array'], function (exports, _array) {
  'use strict';

  Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
  });
  Object.defineProperty(exports, 'default', {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function () {
      return _array.default;
    }
  });
});
```

In first line your read the name of the import `ember-array-helper/helpers/array` from which you can guess on the addon name (first part). Note that you could also open the actual helper exported by addon via developer tools by opening `/assets/addon-tree-output/ember-array-helper/helpers/array.js`. Since the last part is coming from the import, you could easily use that one to search for the file. Now place your breakpoints and inspect this code as much as you like.

The same approach should work in all major browsers.

Comment: wow guys, this is really helpful! Furthermore I realized that one surefire thing to do is create a debug build of the app, outputting 2 js files for app code and vendor code - since these contain everything, this too can be searched and inspected - although I think searching in devtools would be better.